# How should I store and and use gun fire data in a game?

Tags: c++, data-structures

On this game I have 3 defense towers (the number is configurable) which fire a "bullet" every 3 seconds at 30km/h. These defense towers have a radar and they only start firing when the player is under the tower radar. That's not the issue.

My question is how to store the data for the gun fire. I'm not sure exactly what data do I need for each bullet, but one that comes to mind is the position of the bullet of course. Let's assume that I only need to store that (I already have a struct defined for a 3D point) for now.

Should I try to figure it out the maximum bullets the game can have at a particular point and declare an array with that size? Should I use a linked-list? Or maybe something else?

I really have no idea how to do this. I don't need anything fancy or complex. Something basic that just works and it's easy to use and implement is more than enough.

P.S: I didn't post this question on the game development website (despite the tag) because I think it fits better here.

Comment: sorry, but how we are supposed to know the answer? It depends on the characteristics of your game, which we doesn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, fixed length arrays aren't a good idea.

Given your game model, I wouldn't go for any data structure that doesn't allow O(1) removal.  That rules out plain arrays anyway, and might suggest a linked list.  However the underlying details should be abstracted out by using a generic container class with the right attributes.

As for *what* you should store:

1. Position (as you mentioned)
2. Velocity
3. Damage factor (your guns *are* upgradeable, aren't they?)
4. Maximum range (ditto)

**EDIT** <strike>To slightly complicated matters the STL classes always take copies of the elements put in them, so in practise if any of the attributes might change over the object's lifetime you'll need to allocate your structures on the heap and store (smart?) pointers to them in the collection.</strike>

Comment: I don't agree with the final statement. Specifically, if the authoritative copy of the bullet is the one in the vector, and the "original" bullet data is discarded after being inserted, then he should let the vector do his memory management for him.

Comment: @Rob doesn't that imply that any changes to a particular item in the collection can only be done by replacing the entire item?

Comment: That's confusing me. The bullet is moving, I need to keep saving the current bullet position to test for collisions, hits, etc. But like you said, I could probably use pointers to the real data!?

Comment: @Alnitak - No, it doesn't imply that. You can update the state directly in the container. Assuming you have `vector<Bullet> ballisticState`, you can do this: `ballisticState[i].position += 30;`, for example. Similarly, if you use `list<Bullet` and if you have `list<Bullet>::iterator it;` pointing at a valid item in the list, you can do `it->position += 30;`

Comment: @Rob, ah yes - ISTR that when you insert a value into the collection it's copied, but on retrieval it can be used as an lvalue, yes?

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes. Specifically, `front()`, `back()`, `operator[]`, and `iterator::operator*` all return *references*, which can be used as lvalues.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a `std::vector` or `std::list`.  Whatever's easiest.

Caveat: If you are coding for a very constrained platform (slow CPU, little memory), then it might make sense to use a plain-old fixed-size C array.  But that's very unlikely these days.  Start with whatever is easiest to code, and change it later if and only if it turns out you can't afford the abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can start off with `std::vector<BulletInfo>` and see how it works from there. It provides the array like interface but is dynamically re-sizable.

Answer (score 1):

In instances like this I prefer a slightly more complex method to managing bullets.  Since the number of bullets possible on screen is directly related to the number of towers I would keep a small fixed length array of bullets inside each tower class.  Whenever a tower goes to fire a bullet it would search through its array, find an un-used bullet, setup the bullet with a new position/velocity and mark it active.

The slightly more complex part is I like to keep a second list of bullets in an outside manager, say a BulletManager.  When each tower is created the tower would add all its bullets to the central manager.  Then the central manager can be in charge of updating the bullets.

I like this method because it easily allows me to manage memory constrains related to bullets, just tweak the 'number of active towers' number and all of the bullets are created for you.  You don't need to allocate bullets on the fly because they are all pooled, and you don't have just one central pool that you constantly need to change the size of as you add/remove towers.

It does involve slightly move overhead because there is a central manager with a list of pointers.  And you need to be careful to always remove any bullets from a destroyed tower from the central manager.  But for me the benefits are worth it.